# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I try to run my project using Selenium and Java, I am getting this error and I do not know how to solve it. This is happening on VSCode and the SO is Windows 11.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

This is the code I created:

```
WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
browser.navigate().to("http://localhost:8080/leiloes");
browser.quit();
```

I appreciate your help.

Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property of webdriver like below, and you can use get instead of `driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");`

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class TestChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the exe file\\chromedriver.exe");

        // Initialize browser
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Open facebook
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

        // Maximize browser

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

}
```

Comment: You can use the same code in Test method also.

Comment: I already did it but the error persists. This is only happening if I am using localhost. I updated my path below for safety reasons

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class HelloWorldSelenium {
    @Test
    public void hello() {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/path/to/project/leilão/chromedriver.exe");        
        WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
        browser.navigate().to("http://localhost:8080/");
        browser. Quit();
    }

}